# Can't GitHub Pages because of large file which I already deleted (push is ok)

Tags: git, github, github-pages, large-files

I got a github Large files error.

```
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: File FILENAME is 124.07 MB; this exceeds GitHub Enterprise's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To GITHUPURL
```

After various attempts(ex. `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf FILENAME'`, `git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch FILENAME'`, Add to gitignore file, etc), git push works fine without errors.
But when I try to try the github pages I keep getting a big capacity error.
Even though I solved the error when I pushed, why do I keep getting the same error when trying to pages? How can I fix this?

Comment: Are there other big files you didn't remove? Did you remove the files from the branch you deploy, too?

Comment: @dan1st
There are no other large files and I get an error with the same file name. We also removed the file from the branch we deployed.

Comment: Can you make sure the deployed directory/branch is smaller than 1GB? Check out the branch and test this.

Comment: @dan1st yes, deployed directory/branch is about 500MB... 

Comment: Is the whole repository greater than 1GB?